My script takes ~13 seconds per webpage, what can I do to speed this up?
I need to filter out all webpages with 0 listings on Grailed. I have over 500k URLs to go through. I'm using Python and Selenium. My problem is that for every new webpage the script needs to click on the cookie and user login pop-up to access the number of listings. The result is that each webpage takes ~13 seconds to process. For 500k URLs this will take 75 days.
An example link: https://www.grailed.com/designers/acne-studios/casual-pants
All 500k links: https://www.grailed.com/designers/designer-name/category-name
Two approaches I'm figuring out:

Try to block the cookie and user login pop-ups. However I'm not sure if this is possible without saving some sort of user profile, after which I'm worried I'll get blocked by Grailed.

Run multiple instances at the same time, preferably between 13 (~2 weeks) and 130 (~14 hours). However I'm not sure if it'll be costly and how to avoid getting blocked. do I need to use proxies for this?


Please tell me if I'm missing something. My code:
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import os
import time

# Update the PATH environment variable
os.environ['PATH'] += r";C:\Users\rafme\Desktop\Selenium Drivers"

# Read the CSV file
BrandCategoryLinks = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/rafme/Downloads/Test Brands & Categories.csv')

FilteredCategoryLink = []

# Loop through each link in the DataFrame
for index, link in BrandCategoryLinks.iterrows():
    driver = None
    try:
        base_url = link['Links']
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU usage
        chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Disable sandboxing
        chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Disable shared memory usage
        chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")  # Set the window size
        chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        chrome_options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36")
        service = Service(r"C:\Users\rafme\Desktop\Selenium Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)

        driver.get(base_url)

        timeout = 60  # Increase timeout

        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler")))
            reject_button = driver.find_element(By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler")

            # Scroll the element into view using JavaScript
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", reject_button)
            time.sleep(2)  # Wait for the scrolling to complete

            # Click the element
            reject_button.click()
            time.sleep(1)
            reject_button.click()
            time.sleep(1)
        except (NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException):
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
            continue

        # Close the user login modal if it exists
        try:
            elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Modal-Content']")
            ac = ActionChains(driver)
            ac.move_to_element(elem).move_by_offset(250, 0).click().perform()  # clicking away from login window
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error clicking 'User Authentication' button: {e}")
            continue

        # Check listing count
        try:
            listing_count = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,
                                                 "//div[@class='FiltersInstantSearch']//div[@class='feed-item']")
            if len(listing_count) > 1:
                print(f"Found {len(listing_count)} listings on {base_url}")
                FilteredCategoryLink.append(base_url)
            else:
                print(f"Found {len(listing_count)} listings on {base_url}, not enough to keep.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error finding listings: {e}")
            continue

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing link {link}: {e}")
    finally:
        if driver:
            driver.quit()

# Save the filtered categories to CSV
filtered_categories = pd.DataFrame(FilteredCategoryLink, columns=['Link'])
filtered_categories.to_csv('filtered_categories.csv', index=False)

Update:
Big thanks to InspectorG4adget and xoxouser.
I've editted xoxouser's code to 1. filter out all subcategories with less than 25 listings, and 2. parallelize with 10 threads.
Less than 10 minutes later I had collected a CSV file with ~20k designer names, subcategories, and nr of listings. Exactly what I was after, but in xoxouser's fashion: 10,800x faster ;)
Updated code:
import requests
import json
import csv
from urllib.parse import quote
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'X-Algolia-Api-Key': 'bc9ee1c014521ccf312525a4ef324a16',
    'X-Algolia-Application-Id': 'MNRWEFSS2Q'
}

url_designers = 'https://www.grailed.com/api/designers'
req_designers = requests.get(url_designers, headers=headers)
designers = json.loads(req_designers.text)['data']

url_api = 'https://mnrwefss2q-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'
data = []

def fetch_designer_data(des):
    facetFilters = quote(f'[["designers.name:{des["name"]}"]]')
    facets = quote('["category_path"]')
    payload = '{"requests":[{"indexName": "Listing_by_low_price_production", "params": "maxValuesPerFacet=200&hitsPerPage=0&facetFilters=%s&facets=%s"}]}' % (facetFilters, facets)
    req = requests.post(url_api, headers=headers, data=payload)
    listings = json.loads(req.text)['results'][0]['facets']
    designer_data = []
    if 'category_path' in listings:
        for category_path, nr_listings in listings['category_path'].items():
            if nr_listings >= 25:
                designer_data.append({
                    'designer_name': des['name'],
                    'category_path': category_path,
                    'nr_listings': nr_listings
                })
    return designer_data

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(fetch_designer_data, des): des for des in designers}
    for i, future in enumerate(as_completed(futures)):
        designer_data = future.result()
        data.extend(designer_data)
        if (i + 1) % 10 == 0:
            print(f"Processed {i + 1} designers")

# Define the CSV file path
csv_file_path = 'designers_listings_all.csv'

# Write data to CSV
with open(csv_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['designer_name', 'category_path', 'nr_listings']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row)

print(f"Data successfully written to {csv_file_path}")


Use a specific Chrome profile in Selenium (which you logging in upfront and accept the cookies), so the popups wont bother you. Keep the browser(selenium) open, right now you are reopening the browser for each link in BrandCategoryLinks. Do not load unnecessary data (images, ...)

Items seem to load even without clicking the cookie modal. Also, there seems to be a dynamic load - so you'll need an infinite scroll before you count the number of items. Looks like it does in fact hit an API endpoint, which you can mimic with requests to improve speed. Finally, parallelize and use residential proxies

@inspectorG4dget could you provide any more details on what OP needs to do to construct an API request to the right endpoint with the right data?

@ryyyn: Look at the network tab in the dev console of your browser. Look at the XHR tab and see what API calls are being made. Copy the associate request as a curl request and replicate with python's requests module

This seems like it's part of a bigger problem, please clarify how you're going to use the FilteredCategoryLink, and where you got the csv file

if you have 500k URLs to go through, what on earth are you actually doing? Why are you scraping these URLs (i.e. what is the task you need to perform that you think requires scraping this many URLs)?

Find a profiler and check where the code spends its time. Probably in network I/O, but maybe you find something else that's easy to optimize. If it is network I/O, look into async programming. If you only need csv reading / writing, Pandas may be overkill and the standard Python csv may be more lightweight.

As suggested in the comments, it's better to pull the data via API using Python's requests library.
The website currently around 12k designers and 128 subcategories, which would result in up to 1.5M data points. Here are the 3 steps to significantly speed it up:

Looking deeper into the API calls, I found a way to create a single query which would respond with a number of listings per subcategory. So from the original 500k URLs we're down to 12k requests (the total number of designers). 41x throughput improvement.
Moreover, by using requests, it takes just ~0.3s per request, which is an additional 43x improvement compared to 13 seconds.
Lastly, you can run the below code in multiple threads. I tried to run 100 parallel threads without any issues from the server. This, in theory, could bring up to 100x improvement. Watch out, risk of blacklisting your IP.

Putting these things together resulted in ~180,000x speed improvement from your original implementation. In other words, it takes slightly over one minute to pull all the data.
And if it's still not enough, you could add proxies as step #4. Hope this provides some useful insights.
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import quote

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
           'X-Algolia-Api-Key': 'bc9ee1c014521ccf312525a4ef324a16',
           'X-Algolia-Application-Id': 'MNRWEFSS2Q'}

url_designers = 'https://www.grailed.com/api/designers'
req_designers = requests.get(url_designers, headers=headers)
designers = json.loads(req_designers.text)['data']

url_api = 'https://mnrwefss2q-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries'
data = []

for des in designers:
    facetFilters = quote(f'[["designers.name:{des['name']}"]]')
    facets = quote('["category_path"]')
    payload = '{"requests":[{"indexName": "Listing_by_low_price_production", "params": "maxValuesPerFacet=200&hitsPerPage=0&facetFilters=%s&facets=%s"}]}' % (facetFilters, facets)
    req = requests.post(url_api, headers=headers, data=payload)
    listings = json.loads(req.text)['results'][0]['facets']
    if 'category_path' in listings:
        data.append({des['name']: listings['category_path']})
    else:
        data.append({des['name']: {}})

data output looks like this:
[
...
 {'Acne Studios': {'bottoms.denim': 4644, 'tops.sweaters_knitwear': 2266, 'tops.sweatshirts_hoodies': 1658, 'womens_bottoms.jeans': 1122, 'tops.short_sleeve_shirts': 1087, 'bottoms.casual_pants': 1078, 'tops.button_ups': 960, 'outerwear.light_jackets': 591, 'womens_tops.sweaters': 557, 'footwear.lowtop_sneakers': 331, 'tops.long_sleeve_shirts': 295, 'outerwear.heavy_coats': 289, 'bottoms.shorts': 288, 'outerwear.denim_jackets': 279, 'outerwear.bombers': 257, 'womens_bottoms.pants': 211, 'outerwear.leather_jackets': 207, 'accessories.hats': 188, 'womens_tops.sweatshirts': 160, 'womens_tops.short_sleeve_shirts': 159, 'tailoring.blazers': 142, 'womens_footwear.boots': 140, 'outerwear.parkas': 122, 'womens_dresses.midi': 116, 'bottoms.sweatpants_joggers': 108, 'tops.polos': 107, 'accessories.gloves_scarves': 102, 'footwear.hitop_sneakers': 94, 'womens_outerwear.jackets': 91, 'womens_tops.blouses': 90, 'womens_outerwear.coats': 86, 'footwear.boots': 83, 'womens_tops.button_ups': 80, 'bottoms.cropped_pants': 76, 'tops.sleeveless': 74, 'womens_dresses.mini': 65, 'womens_footwear.lowtop_sneakers': 65, 'accessories.bags_luggage': 64, 'womens_tops.long_sleeve_shirts': 64, 'womens_outerwear.denim_jackets': 60, 'accessories.sunglasses': 57, 'womens_outerwear.blazers': 55, 'footwear.leather': 53, 'womens_accessories.scarves': 53, 'womens_outerwear.leather_jackets': 52, 'womens_bottoms.mini_skirts': 47, 'womens_bottoms.midi_skirts': 44, 'tailoring.suits': 41, 'womens_dresses.maxi': 41, 'womens_accessories.hats': 40, 'womens_tops.hoodies': 40, 'womens_tops.tank_tops': 38, 'womens_bottoms.shorts': 37, 'outerwear.vests': 35, 'womens_outerwear.bombers': 31, 'footwear.formal_shoes': 29, 'womens_footwear.heels': 29, 'accessories.jewelry_watches': 25, 'tailoring.formal_trousers': 24, 'womens_tops.crop_tops': 22, 'womens_tops.polos': 22, 'outerwear.raincoats': 19, 'womens_outerwear.down_jackets': 18, 'outerwear.cloaks_capes': 17, 'womens_accessories.miscellaneous': 17, 'womens_bags_luggage.shoulder_bags': 17, 'accessories.misc': 16, 'accessories.wallets': 16, 'footwear.slip_ons': 15, 'womens_footwear.sandals': 14, 'womens_accessories.sunglasses': 13, 'womens_bags_luggage.tote_bags': 12, 'womens_bottoms.joggers': 12, 'accessories.belts': 11, 'accessories.glasses': 11, 'womens_footwear.flats': 11, 'footwear.sandals': 10, 'tops.jerseys': 10, 'womens_footwear.hitop_sneakers': 10, 'womens_footwear.platforms': 9, 'womens_bottoms.leggings': 8, 'womens_bottoms.maxi_skirts': 8, 'accessories.socks_underwear': 7, 'bottoms.swimwear': 7, 'womens_accessories.belts': 7, 'womens_outerwear.vests': 7, 'bottoms.jumpsuits': 6, 'womens_footwear.slip_ons': 6, 'womens_bags_luggage.crossbody_bags': 5, 'womens_bottoms.sweatpants': 5, 'tailoring.vests': 4, 'womens_accessories.socks_intimates': 4, 'womens_accessories.wallets': 4, 'womens_bags_luggage.handle_bags': 4, 'womens_dresses.gowns': 4, 'accessories.periodicals': 3, 'accessories.ties_pocketsquares': 3, 'bottoms.leggings': 3, 'tailoring.formal_shirting': 3, 'womens_bags_luggage.clutches': 3, 'womens_bags_luggage.mini_bags': 3, 'womens_bags_luggage.other': 3, 'womens_jewelry.necklaces': 3, 'womens_outerwear.fur_faux_fur': 3, 'bottoms': 2, 'womens_bags_luggage.backpacks': 2, 'womens_bags_luggage.bucket_bags': 2, 'womens_bottoms.jumpsuits': 2, 'womens_footwear.mules': 2, 'womens_jewelry.bracelets': 2, 'womens_jewelry.earrings': 2, 'tailoring.tuxedos': 1, 'womens_accessories.glasses': 1, 'womens_accessories.hair_accessories': 1, 'womens_jewelry.body_jewelry': 1, 'womens_jewelry.rings': 1, 'womens_outerwear.rain_jackets': 1, 'womens_tops.bodysuits': 1}}, 
 {'A.Coba.Lt': {'footwear.boots': 1, 'tops.sweatshirts_hoodies': 1}},
 {'A Cold Wall': {'tops.short_sleeve_shirts': 293, 'tops.sweatshirts_hoodies': 280, 'footwear.lowtop_sneakers': 187, 'bottoms.sweatpants_joggers': 183, 'outerwear.light_jackets': 148, 'tops.long_sleeve_shirts': 133, 'accessories.bags_luggage': 129, 'bottoms.casual_pants': 108, 'tops.sweaters_knitwear': 71, 'accessories.hats': 61, 'outerwear.vests': 61, 'footwear.boots': 56, 'bottoms.shorts': 54, 'footwear.hitop_sneakers': 52, 'outerwear.heavy_coats': 48, 'tops.button_ups': 47, 'outerwear.raincoats': 30, 'accessories.belts': 24, 'bottoms.denim': 21, 'accessories.misc': 18, 'outerwear.denim_jackets': 18, 'outerwear.parkas': 17, 'outerwear.bombers': 14, 'accessories.gloves_scarves': 13, 'footwear.leather': 11, 'tops.polos': 11, 'footwear.slip_ons': 10, 'womens_bottoms.midi_skirts': 10, 'accessories.jewelry_watches': 8, 'accessories.sunglasses': 7, 'accessories.socks_underwear': 6, 'accessories.wallets': 6, 'tops.sleeveless': 6, 'bottoms.cropped_pants': 5, 'footwear.sandals': 5, 'bottoms.leggings': 4, 'outerwear.cloaks_capes': 4, 'tops.jerseys': 4, 'tailoring.blazers': 3, 'womens_bottoms.jeans': 3, 'womens_footwear.boots': 3, 'womens_footwear.hitop_sneakers': 3, 'accessories.periodicals': 2, 'footwear.formal_shoes': 2, 'womens_bottoms.shorts': 2, 'womens_outerwear.rain_jackets': 2, 'womens_tops.sweaters': 2, 'accessories.glasses': 1, 'bottoms.jumpsuits': 1, 'bottoms.swimwear': 1, 'tailoring.suits': 1, 'womens_bottoms.leggings': 1, 'womens_outerwear.vests': 1, 'womens_tops.button_ups': 1}}
...
]


